# Visual Studio 2019 Add Existing (form) not working after PowerShell UNBLOCK-FILE

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019, resx, mark-of-the-web

I was getting an error to remove the "mark of the web" from a `.resx` file and so I opened PowerShell as administrator, navigated to the folder in question, and issued an `Unblock-File -Path myfile.resx` command.  I've also done it using the full path.

Now I am trying to bring the form into the project using `Add Existing`, but the `.resx` file is not being imported. However, for another form, when I choose `Add Existing` and click on the form's `.cs` file, Visual Studio (2019) brings all three files into the project in one fell swoop, its`.cs`, its`designer.cs` and its`.resx`; but on the other form, the `.resx` file is not imported. In fact, Visual Studio does not even display `myfile.resx` in the list of files when I choose `Add Existing`.

What has `Unblock-File` done that would make the file invisible within Visual Studio?

Comment: You can't add the resx file by itself.  It automatically gets loaded with the form.  IF you copy from another project the for you must copy all three files.  When modifying the form it may not open after modification.  Use VS and check if the Form Design appears.

Comment: I am not trying to add the resx file by itself. I am clicking on the form's `.cs` file. With one form, it works, and all three files are imported into the project using Add Existing. But with the other form, the one whose `.resx` file was "unblocked" in PowerShell, that approach is not working; moreover, that resx file is not even in the list shown by Visual Studio.  Visual Studio fails to compile because that resx file has stuff the form needs.

Comment: No.  The designer.cs has errors.  You could create a new project with just a blank form.  Then copy the designer.cs from old project to new project and see if form works.  If it doesn't comment out the code in the designer.cs and slow add until you find the error.

Comment: @jdweng: The error in the designer's code is where it is looking for a resource. The result of a `resources.GetObject` call is being assigned to a control property.  And an error in the Designer.cs wouldn't explain why the resx file isn't being displayed in the file listing when Add Existing is clicked, when other resx files are being shown in that listing.

Comment: I've seen similar issues in c# when the designer.cs has errors.  The Initialize in the constructor fails and no form is shown.